# How to convert a Python file docstring's to HTML

Tags: python, documentation

Is there a simple way to convert a `.py` to an HTML by displaying its function API's and `docstring`'s? I read up on Sphinx - but that seems to be for a big project. I am just trying to find a way to create an HTML from a `.py` file with just its function definition and `docstring`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My hand written api documentation handler do something like that.

```
import inspect
inspect.getmembers(MyClass, predicate=inspect.ismethod)
```

will return you a list of all available methods. First objest is the string representation of the method name, so you can use simple filter functions to filter out some of them. My api filters out methods started with `_` (which are inner methods and must not be reachable from api) like

```
    filter(lambda x: not x.startswith('_'), [x[0] for x in inspect.getmembers(MyClass, predicate=inspect.ismethod)])
```

Second object is instance method of related method. you can use it to call `__doc__` to get docstring or any other method you can call with a method instance

```
for item in inspect.getmembers(MyClass, predicate=inspect.ismethod):
    print item[0]
    print item[1].__doc__
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it without any tools.
First you need to get data. Here is very basic example:

```
"""My module"""

def foo():
    """Some function"""
    pass

def bar():
    """Another function"""
    pass

class Spam(object):
    """Some object"""
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import types

    defs = set(locals().keys()).difference(set(__builtins__.keys())) 

    if __doc__:
        print 'Module:'
        print __doc__, '\n'

    for name in defs:
        object_ = locals()[name]
        if type(object_) is types.FunctionType:
            print "Function %s:" % object_.__name__
            print object_.__doc__, '\n'
        elif type(object_) is type:
            print "Class %s:" % object_.__name__
            print object_.__doc__, '\n'
```

And output will be:

```
Module:
My module 

Function bar:
Another function 

Class Spam:
Some object 

Function foo:
Some function
```

To get html you can use a template engine, for example [Mako](http://www.makotemplates.org/). Make a template and pass data from `__doc__` to it and that should do the job.

**EDIT:** Here is way to get signature from a function:

```
>>> def foo(spam, eggs):
...     bar = spam + eggs
...     return bar
>>> varnames = foo.func_code.co_varnames
>>> argcount = foo.func_code.co_argcount
>>> '%s(%s)' % (foo.__name__, ', '.join(varnames[:argcount]))
0: 'foo(spam, eggs)'
```

Comment: +1, no need for libraries. But: you solved only half of the problems, the signature of the functions is not printed.

Comment: Yes, but it is usually described in docstring, isn't it? And I have no idea how to get signature from function object.

Comment: Ideally yes , but practically no . So I want the signature too !